# Network Interfaces Do Not Function When Ubuntu Is Installed On An Asus 'Striker Extreme' Motherboard

Tags: networking, drivers, dhcp

I am attempting to install Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS on my computer.  This computer is based around an [Asus 'Striker Extreme'](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/Striker_Extreme/) motherboard.  I can install Ubuntu, but the machine cannot connect to the network.  The installer and `modprobe` both claim to recognize the network interfaces of the motherboard, but there is no network connectivity.

When the machine's interfaces are configured to use DHCP, they claim to be sending out DHCPDISCOVER messages, but looking at the log on my DHCP server, I see no DHCPDISCOVER messages received and no DHCPOFFER messages sent out.  When the machine's interfaces are configured to use static IP addresses, they can't communicate with the rest of the network.

I tested the cable separately: it works.  I tested with different DHCP servers: no change. I tested with a different switch: no change.

When I use Google to seek an answer to this problem, I end up with answers [like this one on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=352716) or [like this one elsewhere on the same forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-387312.html), which are dated advice and which don't work for me: I can go through the steps of telling modprobe to do something different, but this does not solve the problem and the symptoms that I am experiencing do not change.

How can I get this machine connected to my network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to this question are no longer verifiable: the motherboard died entirely a few weeks after the question was posted. So it's now impossible to accept an answer.